# React Native Navigation change tabsStyle on runtime

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using **startTabBasedApp API** with three tabs but I need to change the tabBar background color for some of my screens. Is it possible to change the tabBar background color at runtime?

**Example**:

- Screen 1 -> `tabBar { tabBarBackgroundColor: "red" }`
- Screen 2 -> `tabBar { tabBarBackgroundColor: "Blue" }`
- Screen 2 -> `tabBar { tabBarBackgroundColor: "yellow" }`

I found this section in the documentation: [Doc](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-navigator) but it doesn't support tabBarBackgroundColor property. Is there a way of doing this functionality?

PS: I am quite new to React / React-native.

Answer (score 0):

Styling BottomTabs during runtime should be possible now that [#2524](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/2524) was merged. Try upgrading to v1.1.339

Comment: yogevbd: Revert "setStyle to style the according TabBar. I Was 5 hours to late :(

Comment: We're still trying to iron out some issues in that pr

Comment: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/2539 is merged, try to update and use `navigator.setStyle(...)` to update tab style

Comment: This feature stopped working after I updated to 1.1.367. Is this still being developed?

I used it like this:

`static navigatorStyle = {
        tabBarBackgroundColor: "red",
  };`

Comment: Unfortunately it was reverted. We tried merging it a few times but faced wired side effects. We don't really have the manpower to support the feature now, but it will be supported in v2